# Advanced JS bundling: Some dependencies already included under certain JS Bundle are loading separately

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, frontend, advanced-bundling

[image]I am facing an issue with some dependencies that were already included in some bundle are loading separately as seen in the browser console. Could you please share yours insights into this? Please refer the screenshots below. For example, common.js included under Bundle/default is loading separately as seen in the second screenshot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more info about how have you bundled the JS please?

Comment: @Ben Crook, yes. I have bundled the JS under the modules node. Let me paste the entire for you to have a quick look. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ben Crook, fixed the issue when I found out that I had deleted a few dependencies starting with text!. thanks for your trying to assist, I have a final JS error that say "catalog.js:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at catalog.js:22"  Can you please tell me any possible solution?

Comment: That sounds like 'jquery' isn't included in your list of dependencies, if that isn't the case I'm unsure sorry.

Comment: @Ben Crook, that is also fixed thanks for your comment anyway.